# Having VMs running on a host identified as seperate machines (UBUNTU)

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I currently run several virtual machines ( with virtual box) on an ubuntu system.

My goal is to configure a network so as it looks like the internet communication doesn't come from the same one and only host on which the VMs are running - I want the router to think that it is communicating with separate machines - so the virtual machines running on the host actually look like different hosts.

**How do I get it to 'trick' the network and router to identify them as separate machines ?**

my PC is connected via Wifi to the router.
I already created a virtual bridge with nmcli and netplan configurations. It seems that the bridge is only working with ethernet - so the bridge is useless. Seemingly it's only possible for ethernet, unless you got some extra hardware (not a virtual bridge adapter).

Comment: well in what I ve learned, when it comes to network traffic, if the vm is running on a host you would still be able to find out that it s running on the host machine, or am I wrong ?

Comment: for ex. if I m surfing in the internet on a VM, fine the VM does have it s own IP address. However the traffic is routed through the host and then to the router right ? so cookies would notice that basically the host is doing the query right ?        (sry I m not a professional)

Comment: if you are using virtualbox, are your virtual NICs in Bridged mode? that gives each VM its own IP on the network, and devices other than the host (including other VMs) will see the VMs as standalone boxes.

Comment: only I f I had a bridge, then it traffic might not be routed through the host right?

Comment: @Frank Thomas no I haven t turned on bridged mode yet.

Comment: @Frank Thomas  problem is my pc is only connected via WIFI, and the virtual bridge adapter setup by nmcli seems only to work over ethernet.

Comment: the setting I'm reffering to is in Virtualbox configuration. not somthing you need additional software to set up, as long as the host has a network connection. its just part of the virtual nic definition, and configures how the VM will work with the virtual network, and the LAN network the host is connected to. also note, cookies don't care about network level anything. they are a software thing, and are just about how browsers work. the browser also don't care about the network, as long as its working properly.

Comment: well it seems like I only have those options (in the Network tab of the virtual box preferences):  
    Not Attached,
    NAT,
    NAT Network,

    Internal Network,
    Host-Only Adapter,
    Generic Driver
                                         And 'bridged adapter' is missing.  that s why I went on to setup a seperate bridge in hope thtat the option 'bridged adapter' was occuring afterwards.

Comment: I meant cookies / trackers. trackers are monitoring the browser activity and which contents are researched by each IP address.

Comment: isolated machines is what I (probably)  want. I don t want the network traffic from the host to be related to what is (re)searched/ browsed inside the VMs running on the host for example.  I want to understand how this works                     \n this means every VM has its own cookies and trackers, and it s not possible to say that they re running on the same host.

Comment: So then switch your networking type to Host Only. Then the VM's cannot talk to each other. Host Only has limitations of course. There is a basic confusion in this topic that a VM can be isolated and then connected when desired.

Comment: still believe that bridged

Comment: Bridge mode is working with WiFi as well, but IPv6 needs to be disabled in the VM guest.

Comment: nice, thx (for the info) @Michalng

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question is a bit difficult as it appears there is confusion as to how networking works, and the "identify them as separate machines" requirement is very open to interpretation.  Nonetheless the following may be useful, if a bit simplified.

**Each network interface has (or should have) a unique MAC address, with IP addresses associated with it.  By ensuring that (a) the MAC address of the VM client is unique and (b) ensuring that this is not obscured by the the VM host will largely meet your goal.**   In order to do this you need to make the host perform like a hub/switch - which means creating a bridge of some sort.  (I've never bothered with Virtualbox - I know that you can do this in KVM)

Home routers are typically configured to use NAT to share a whole lot of non-routed addresses (1918 IPs - eg 192.168.x.x, 10.x.x.x and 172.16-32.x.x).  Systems outside your home will not easily be able to differentiate machines behind NAT.    You could get around this limitation by using VPN's to move the endpoint of the VM to appear like its elsewhere.

Cookies are not related to a VM appearing unique. Cookies are information passed between web clients and servers.  You can defeat/change the impact of cookies by using private browsing, different browsers or multiple profiles.   While Cookies can be used to tell sessions are linked they in no way relate to VMs - they work at the application level, far above the network level.

Comment: firstly I wanted to say thank you. that clearified a bit and showed me that bridging might be the solution.  according to what you wrote, it seems like because of the NAT of the home router, it doesn t make a big difference if I bridge right (unless I d use VPN) ?

Comment: second question: however if it comes to trackers that are present in the internet, the IP address is stored (in servers of the website) in order to be able to map the content researched by the user, so using different VMs with different IP addresses (in bridged mode) would be the solution for anonymous browsing right ?     you d search one thing in one VM, and other stuff in the other right ? they look like different computers / real machines in the network, not like NAT  or Host-only.

Comment: If you are worried about tracking on the internet (ie **outside your LAN**), then you should not need to use bridging to create a machine that appears separate.  (Assuming IPV4 here) - In a typical SOHO environment, different VMs with different IPs wont make any difference as the IPs you are using are translated by the router and never seen by the server - ie all a server can tell from an IP address is the routers IP. Anonymous browsing implies using a different set of cookies for browsers, and possibly limiting plugins to prevent fingerprinting...

Comment: I think that you have asked an XY question - rather then asking about VM's, why don't you ask about what you are actually trying to achieve.    Also, do you know if you are using IPV6?  (IPV6 can be used to uniquely identify computers bypassing NAT in some cases).   What kind of Internet connection do you have?   Are you aware of https://coveryourtracks.eff.org/ - this can help you understand and identify how you can be tracked and can help you make yourself more anonymous.

Comment: If you are worried about being tracked around the Internet and marketted to, simply getting an adblocker, and using plugins like ghostery and cookie autodelete can go a long way.  If you really want your VM to appear totally seperate from your main computer, set it up with whatever kind of networking gets you on the Internet and then use a VPN over it.  That will make it close-to-impossible for remote parties to connect the VM and HOST systems - and using a VPN can abstract you to a different apparent location as well (and, of-course, giving your VM an alternative IP address)

Comment: well I would achieve my goal. this is simply for understanding purposes. it s not about trackers - trackers are just and example of realworld use cases, that in my point of view seem feasable. but still, thank you .. that s big information for me.

Comment: the idea here is simply that it could be a router of some public space; and even in a SOHO there could be different computers from different people, right?       do the VMs communicate with their own IP address, or does it depend on whether it s NAT or bridged ? what I understand now is that if you use bridges the VMs would seem to be different PCs right ?  (like you wrote)

Comment: but yeah if the server can only see the routers address it wouldn t matter I guess  and I like the VPN idea.

Comment: (when behind NAT/a SOHO router) VMs communicate on unique IP addresses which are changed by the router to its WAN IP address. The IP address of your VM or computers dont leave your LAN. Whethrr you do NAT or bridging or.something else, data passing through a NAY gateway makes the choice irrelevant as far as devices on the wider internet are concsrned.  The bit you might be missing is that for most protocols the IP addresses are combined with ports which help NAT routers to link connections to servers with  to machines on thr LAN

Comment: let s say I m for IT - Security on my VMs. that means I m practicing IT security on one of the VMs to defend against attackers, for some crucial tasks running on the VMs.  Now one attacker gets the Idea of attacking the host. In a NAT, would he be able to spot the host machine/s, or do every machine look the same ?    (I probably know the answer - still some question there.)   If the attacker would be able to spot the host machine immediately then the VM s had trouble to run.

Comment: This is getting off topic and should be a seperate question. In standard NAT an attacker cant look into your network past the router except for via ports forwarded on the router - so any visibility would be leaked by the application attached to tjose ports. This is not applucable in most home networks.